# Make tween speeds align for linear and cubic ease

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I would like to have linear ease for an object and Back ease to the same point.
I would also like that duration or tweening speed is the same for until the object hits the point, but then Back ease still has that time that it takes to pass the target and return back.

is there some formula to calculate the duration of Back ease to match the speed of linear ease?

for example:

```
 var easeParams:array = [2];
 var duration:Number = 1;

 TweenLite.to(normalObject,duration,{y:30,ease:Linear.easeOut});
 TweenLite.to(backObject,duration,{y:30,ease:Back.easeOut,easeParams:easeParams}
```

In this example back object will appear to run faster, because in duration the back ease is calculated and I want it to go the same spead.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you should pass `easeParams` in the second tween as well? These tweens are made so that you supply the duration and the tween runs for this duration.

Comment: Yo,
ease params just make custom way of backEase going trough and turning back thus making bigger amplitude.

Comment: Quoting official docs: `easeParams is an Array of extra parameter values to feed the easing equation (beyond the standard 4). This can be useful with easing equations like Elastic that accept extra parameters like the amplitude and period. Most easing equations, however, don't accept extra parameters so you won't need to pass in any easeParams.` Linear easing does not use extra parameters (while Back easing does).

Comment: Yes, I use it only in back ease, this was typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* I got you right, you want it to look like this (each arrow representing a tick of a tween):

```
Linear: → → → → → →|

Back:   → → → → → → → →
                   |← ←
```

The tween using the Back easing would obviously require more time than the Linear tween.

And what's more, you will not be able to synchronize them (the speed will be different anyways) as the Back easing accelerates cubically, while the Linear easing is monotonous. Refer to any plots of common easing types. These here, for instance: http://easings.net/

[image]

So, what you got to do is to either use the Back tween with zero overshoot instead of Linear, or use Linear instead of the Back in the first part of backObject movement and use a separate tween for overshoot after the linear part finishes.

**UPDATE:**

Here's how to make both tweens reach target value simultaneously.
The speed is not the same though.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import com.greensock.TweenLite
import com.greensock.data.TweenLiteVars;
import com.greensock.easing.Linear;
import com.greensock.easing.Back;

// *** actual solution ***
var overshoot:Number = 3; // amount of overshoot for Back easing
var durationBack:Number = 3;
// the formula to make both tweens reach target value simultaneously
var durationLinear:Number = durationBack/(overshoot+1); 

// test sprites

var linearSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
linearSprite.graphics.lineStyle(20, 0xFF);
linearSprite.graphics.lineTo(1,0);
linearSprite.x = 50;
linearSprite.y = 50;
this.addChild(linearSprite);

var backSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
backSprite.graphics.lineStyle(20, 0xFF00);
backSprite.graphics.lineTo(1,0);
backSprite.x = 50;
backSprite.y = 80;
this.addChild(backSprite);

// tweening

var linearParams:TweenLiteVars = new TweenLiteVars();
linearParams.ease(Linear.easeOut);
linearParams.prop("x", 300);
var linearTween:TweenLite = new TweenLite(linearSprite, durationLinear, linearParams);

var backParams:TweenLiteVars = new TweenLiteVars();
backParams.ease(Back.easeOut, [overshoot]);
backParams.prop("x", 300);
var backTween:TweenLite = new TweenLite(backSprite, durationBack, backParams);
```

So, what I would do to make both sprites move in the same manner is launching a Back tween and moving the other sprite along by just assigning coordinates every frame for `durationLinear` seconds as calculated above.